# In .NET 7 / EF Core 7, can value conversions reference other properties of the same entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I am trying to convert a field on way in from the database, and also on its way out to the database. The tricky part is, I would like to use data from one column to affect data in a different column.

This has worked for me successfully when I hard-code some of the information needed, but I would like to use information from another column as part of the conversion process. Is that possible? I thought of using a dataservice inside the conversion, on the same context - but it would need the rows primary key, and might make it do an extra query for every record the result -- plus I couldn't even get that to work. Any ideas would be great, thanks for your time!

```
// This works:
var converter1 = new ValueConverter<DateTime, DateTime>(
            from => MyClass.MyFromMethod(from, "my static text"),
            to => MyClass.MyToMethod(to, "my other static text")
        );

// This does NOT work:  (I want to replace the static text above with somehow getting data from a different column in same row here)
var converter2 = new ValueConverter<DateTime, DateTime>(
            from => MyClass.MyFromMethod(from, entity.Property(e => e.OtherColumn).SomehowGetValue()),
            to => MyClass.MyToMethod(to, entity.Property(e => e.OtherColumn).SomehowGetValue())
        );

// called like this:
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("MyTable");
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.MyIdColumn, "MyIndex");
            //generated code here..
            entity.Property(e => e.MyDateColumn).HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasConversion(converter1); //switching to converter2 ideally!
            //more generated code here..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [limitations section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#limitations) of *Value Conversions*:

> There is currently no way to spread a conversion of one property to multiple columns or vice-versa

So what you are trying to do is not supported at the moment.

What I did for a low-impact scenario or one-off utilities in the past is to have an unmapped property in my model that does the conversion.

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public int NeedsConversion { get; set; }
    public int ConvertInfo { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int DependsOnConversion
    {
        get
        {
            return DoConvert(this.NeedsConversion, this.ConvertInfo);
        }
        set
        {
            this.NeedsConversion = DoConvertBack(value, this.ConvertInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

The next part is just my personal opinion and there will people who disagree...

When I design databases I tend to think of then as a rather *stupid* storage layer whose sole purpose is to store data in a save and persistent way. That *raw* data is processed by what I call *business logic layer*.

Oftentimes conversions depend on some kind of *business rule* (e.g: *If this value equals `Foo` we have to factor in `Bar` to the final value*). I do not want my *storage layer* to have that kind of knowledge (that type of stuff goes in the *business layer*). I personally would only allow small, atomic conversions (The [build-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#built-in-converters) converters are examples of what I mean by *small and atomic*) in the *storage layer*. Everything more complex than that goes inside the *business layer* (or an intermediate that *translates* the *business layer* into *storage layer*).

My approach for that looks like this:

```cs
/// The model class that is mapped by EF core
public class FooStorage
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }

    public int Bar { get; set; }

    public int Baz { get; set; }
}

public class StorageToBusiness
{
    public FooBusiness Convert(FooStorage storage)
    {
        return new FooBusiness
        {
            //Management tole me I have to multiply by this magic 42
            CalculatedFooBar = storage.Bar + storage.Baz * 42
        };
    }
}

/// The business object 
public class FooBusiness
{
    public int CalculatedFooBar { get; set; }
}
```

Thay way we have separated *storage logic* from *business logic*